# How do I see Android logs that were logged before connecting to Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logging

Is there a way to see Android logs that were logged before connecting to the Android Studio?

I have an app that tracks GPS location. The issue is that it terminates after some time and I get the Android system message that says "Application Terminated"

I want to see what went wrong and where. When I connect Android studio later, it shows logs that happened from time it is connected.

I want the logs from past.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can try to resolve:

1) I generally write logs when I have such cases to test.

```
public static void writeToFile(String msg) {
        Log.d("MyApp", msg);
        try {
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                FileOutputStream dio = null;
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyApp_File_Logs.txt");
                if (file != null) {
                    try {
                        dio = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
                        dio.write((msg+"\n").getBytes());
                        dio.close();
                        dio = null;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyApp", "Exception in writeToFile(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

So instead of Log.d , Use this Utility method. You can add time in the message to be more precise.
Done forget to give **write external storage permission** to you app

2) Once you see crash , go to command prompt 
and use the below commands:

```
adb shell
logcat -b crash
```

You might see something in this, if you connect within a minute or so

3) Increase the "Logger Buffer Size " in your developer options , but in this case you will see delay in getting logs when you connect your device to adb and open logcat.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a log module into your app,let log module output your app's log into local file,like [logger](https://github.com/orhanobut/logger)